# XSS inside a javascript

Tags: xss, javascript

Can an XSS be craft inside the following JS.

```
$(function () {
            $("#panel").find(".form").each(function (index) {
                var that = this;

                $(that).overload();
            });
            $("#panel").find(".form").find("[name=link]").each(function (index) {
                var that = this;

                $(that).on("click", function (event) {
                    $(that).select();
                });
            });
            $("#panel").find(".form").find("[href=#show]").each(function (index) {
                var that = this;

                $(that).on("click", function (event) {
                    prompt("HardcodedText", $(that).text());
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The page url is something like so https://www.mylabtest.com#show
I tried the following but neither worked

`https://www.mylabtest.com#show]");+alert(1);//`

`https://www.mylabtest.com#show]");<script>alert(1);</script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would have helped if you would have provided with the HTML code as well. However, i think the reason why it does not work is because the value of the hash anchor is not being utilized in the JavaScript.

It would have been exploited as [DOM based XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS) if this value was being used in JavaScript somewhere. Here's is an example of code vulnerable to DOM based XSS:

URL: http://www.example.com/page.html?default=French

```
Select your language:
<select><script>    
document.write("<OPTION value=1>"+document.location.href.substring(document.location.href.indexOf("default=")+8)+"</OPTION>");    
document.write("<OPTION value=2>English</OPTION>");    
</script></select>
```

Comment: You are 100% right , i assume it was being used :(